Error rendering document: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'part')
const Docxtemplater = require('docxtemplater');
const PizZip = require('pizzip');
var ImageModule = require('open-docxtemplater-image-module');
const JSZip = require("jszip");

// Step 1: Add image placeholder to the DOCX template
const contentBuffer = await downloadFromURL(template.sampleTemplate.url);

// Step 2: Add image placeholder to the DOCX template
const modifiedTemplateBuffer = await addPlaceholderToDocx(contentBuffer);
     // Step 2: Load the modified template into PizZip and Docxtemplater
     const zip = new PizZip(modifiedTemplateBuffer);

     // Image handling options for Docxtemplater
     const imageOptions = {
         async getImage(tagValue) {
             console.log("Fetching image from URL: ", tagValue);
             const img = await downloadFromURL(tagValue);
             return img;
         },
         getSize(img, tagValue, tagName) {
             // Return image size (width, height). Adjust this as needed.
             return [150, 150]; 
         }
     };

     const imageModule = new ImageModule(imageOptions);
     const doc = new Docxtemplater(zip, {
         paragraphLoop: true,
         linebreaks: true,
         modules: [imageModule] // Attach image module
     });

     // Step 3: Replace the placeholders with actual data (including image URLs)
     doc.setData(payload);

     // Step 4: Render the document
     try {
         doc.render();
     } catch (renderError) {
         console.error("Error rendering document:", renderError);
         throw renderError;
     }

async function addPlaceholderToDocx(docBuffer) {
const originZip = await JSZip.loadAsync(docBuffer);
  // Find the document XML in the zip file (it's in the word/document.xml file)
  const originDocumentFile = originZip.file(/^word\/document[0-9]*.xml$/)[0];
  let originDocumentXml = await originDocumentFile.async("string");

  // Insert placeholder at the beginning of the document body
  const startIndex = originDocumentXml.indexOf("<w:body>") + 8;
    originDocumentXml = originDocumentXml.slice(0, startIndex) + '<w:p><w:pPr><w:jc            w:val="center"/></w:pPr><w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve">{%image%}</w:t></w:r></w:p>' +    originDocumentXml.slice(startIndex);

  // Update the document in the zip
  originZip.file(originDocumentFile.name, originDocumentXml);

  // Generate the updated DOCX buffer
  const updatedDocxBuffer = await originZip.generateAsync({ type: 'nodebuffer' });
  const outputFilePath = path.join(__dirname, 'output_with_image.docx');
  fs.writeFile(outputFilePath, updatedDocxBuffer, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.error('Error writing the file:', err);
    } else {
        console.log('Word document generated successfully with the image at:', outputFilePath);
    }
  });

 return updatedDocxBuffer;
}

When i try to render image in doc using docxtemplate and open-docxtemplater-image-module. I am getting above issue. I tried most of the solutions but it's not working.Can anybody solve.Thanks in advance.`

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
